# Unexpected char '\' build.gradle

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I had recently imported my Eclipse project into Studio. I exported it via gradle export from Eclipse.  After importing I am getting this error.

```
Error:(16, 0) Cause: startup failed:
build file 'D:\Android\Projects\MainDIr\Project\build.gradle': 16: unexpected char: '\' @ line 16, column 34.
               java.srcDirs = ['libs\ormlite-android','libs\ormlite-core','src']
                                    ^

1 error
```

4 lines in my build.gradle is marked as red. These are referencing to libs folder libraries path. All my libraries are being imported successfully.

```
main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['libs\ormlite-android','libs\ormlite-core','src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['libs\ormlite-android','libs\ormlite-core','src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['libs\ormlite-android','libs\ormlite-core','src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['libs\ormlite-android','libs\ormlite-core','src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
```

Comment: Try with (/) forward slash ?

Comment: try in this manner['src/main/res', src/main/res2']

Comment: Forward Slash sloved it. @Raghavendra Thanks.Sorting out the sdk

Comment: @Googler Glad! that helped:)

Answer (score 5):

> unexpected char '\'

Add `/` instead of `\` . Then **Clean-Rebuild** and **RUN** .

**Example**

```
 aidl.srcDirs =  ['libs/ormlite-android','libs/ormlite-core','src']
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a double backslash `\\` to escape the backslash

```
main {
    manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
    java.srcDirs = ['libs\\ormlite-android','libs\\ormlite-core','src']
    resources.srcDirs = ['libs\\ormlite-android','libs\\ormlite-core','src']
    aidl.srcDirs = ['libs\\ormlite-android','libs\\ormlite-core','src']
    renderscript.srcDirs = ['libs\\ormlite-android','libs\\ormlite-core','src']
    res.srcDirs = ['res']
    assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Using this solve this issue Its Working